# Inserting 1 million records in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two tables and in both tables  I get 1 million records  .And I am using cron job  every night for inserting records  .In first table I am truncating the table first and then inserting the records and in second table I am updating and inserting record according to primary key. I am using mysql as my database.My problem is  I need to do this task each day but I am unable to insert all data .So what can be the possible solution for this problem

Comment: You can inch toward a solution with some detail. Such is not seen above.

Comment: "but I am unable to insert all data" Why?

Answer (score 0):

Important is to set off all kind of actions and checks MySQL wants to perform when posting data, like autocommit, indexing, etc.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

Because if you do not do this, MySQL does a lot of work after every record added, and it adds up, when the process is proceeding, resulting in a very slow processing and importing in the end, and may not complete in one day.

Answer (score -2):

If you must use MySql : For the first table, disable the indexes, do the inserts, than enable indexes. This will works faster.

Alternatively MongoDb will be faster, and Redis is very fast.

Comment: If a Rails user was going to switch databases from MySQL, their first thought ought to be PostgreSQL. But this seems like rather premature advice.

Comment: My main advice was disabling indexes. It was a good one, and down voting me for that was not cool. PostgreSQL is not so much faster the MySql, Redis is. Depands on your needs it could be a great solution. Especially for temporary data (like this case).

Comment: I don't know why you were down-voted or who down-voted you. I think it's unclear what problem the OP has ... maybe it's a performance one, but at the moment it's a really low-quality question (which I *have* down-voted)